# QGIS: Copy all attributes of polyline layer when converting it to point layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, convert, attribute-joins, lines-to-points

I want to add attributes from a polyline layer to a vector point layer.

The polyline is railway network. It has been divided into segments automatically, where as the attributes apply for each segment. To process the data further I had to convert the polyline into points. I wanted defined distances in between so I chose to use the plugin QChaninage. Now I got points in my defined distance. But in the attribute table there aren't any of the original attributes that where in the vectorlines table. How can I connect those attributes with my points?

I guess that vectorlines only store attributes at the end or beginning of these segments, but the point layer I created has points laying in between those segments.

I already tried to use tools from the toolbox (e.g *Join attributes by location tool*) but until now the attributes have been copied only to those points that are located exactly on the segment beginnings or endings of the original polyline.

I hope I am able to make my problem clear enough, if not please feel free to ask for further details. I am quite new to qgis.

edit: I also tried to intersect the original polyline with the attributes I want with my point layer but still only the segment beginnings and endings got the attributes I want, but not all the points.

Comment: Just allow for some uncertainty when you `join attributes by location` by setting the accuracy to something like 1 or 2 (map units).

Comment: I would really like to try out your answer but I don't know where to set the accuracy. Could you maybe show me how your mask looks like and where to fill in the accuracy?

Comment: If you're working with QGIS 3.x, you might have to buffer your points first.

Comment: I've tried that and I am really glad it worked, thank you very much for your help.